# Getting the OrbitViewController in librviz

Tags: ros, librviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, ROS community.

I have been using **librviz** with Qt on ROS **kinetic** in order to create an interactive visualization of points cloud, paths, etc for an application. My problem is as follows. I am trying to change the camera distance of rviz current viewController using the librviz documentation [1] with **C++**. I have set the view controller to *rviz::OrbitViewController* [2], so using its function *zoom(float amount)* would be rather straightforward. The problem is that the *getCurrent()* function of the view manager only returns a *rviz::ViewController*, which means that the child functions of *rviz::OrbitViewController* cannot be accessed.

For example, this is what I want to do :

```
  // Set as the Orbit view controller
  QString class_id = "rviz/Orbit";
  manager_->getViewManager()->setCurrentViewControllerType(class_id);
  ...
  // When the zoom button is clicked
  manager_->getViewManager()->getCurrent()->zoom(1.0); // doesn't work
```

But the function zoom doesn't exist in the parent rviz::ViewController, only in the child rviz::OrbitViewController. My question is quite similar to https://answers.ros.org/question/295527/how-to-control-camera-distance-using-librviz-in-custom-qt-gui/. There were no answers unfortunately. Thank you for your time.

Julien Audet

[1] http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rviz/html/c++/index.html

[2] http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rviz/html/c++/classrviz_1_1OrbitViewController.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318060/getting-the-orbitviewcontroller-in-librviz/) by [Julien Audet](https://answers.ros.org/users/40390/julien-audet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2019-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of getting the OrbitViewController class directly, it is possible to simply change the current view controller properties using the function subProp->setValue. For example, you can change the distance with :

```
     manager_->getViewManager()->getCurrent()->subProp("Distance")->setValue("20");
```

Hope this helps somebody else.

---

Originally posted by [Julien Audet](https://answers.ros.org/users/40390/julien-audet/) with karma: 76 on 2019-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0